# state lost after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Currently i have a function that sets the states from the props,
it works just fine but after refresh the state is empty because the props is lost

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.loadvalues();
}


loadvalues = () => {
  this.setState({
    email: this.props.user.emails[0].address,
    name: this.props.user && this.props.user.hasOwnProperty('name') ? this.props.user.name : '',
    mobileNumber: this.props.user && this.props.user.hasOwnProperty('mobileNumber') ? this.props.user.mobileNumber : '',
  });
}
```

As you can see here the thing is that after refresh this.props.user isnt loaded and this.props.user.hasOwnProperty returns false even though it returned true before refresh
what's the solution for this?

Comment: How are you passing the props? When does the component mount? A little more insight from outside the component would help identify the issue

Comment: i pass the props as arguments in the constructor and i am also using meteor

Comment: @sdybskiy any solution?

Comment: I understand both of those things, that still doesn’t tell me how the component gets the props in the first place. What is the parent component that passes these values as props? Does it work if you replace this.props.user with Meteor.user()?